# Accumulate on Map

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, accumulate

I can't get this rather simple code to compile. I get the error, `could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &&' from 'int'`. Do I need to pass some custom summing function to accumulate? Or perhaps is there a simpler way to get the sum of all second values in the map? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>  


int main()
{

map<int, int> m; 

m[1] = 1;
m[2] = -1;
m[3] = 1;
m[4] = 2;

int sum = accumulate(m.begin(), m.end(), 0);
cout << sum;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may not use algorithm std::accuulate in its simple form for a container of type std::map. You need use the algorithm with binary operation and to use possibly a lambda expression as the binary operation.
For example

```
int sum = accumulate( m.begin(), m.end(), 0,
                      []( int acc, std::pair<int, int> p ) { return ( acc + p.second ); } );
```

Answer (score 1):

An `std::map<int, int>` contains `std::pair<const int, int>` elements. [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) does not know what to do with those. But you can fix this problem by passing it a suitable functor. For example, to accumulate the keys:

```
int fun(int i, const std::pair<const int, int>& rhs)
{
  return i + rhs.second;
}
int sum = accumulate(m.begin(), m.end(), 0, fun);
```

Note you can simplify this by using a lambda, if you don't need to use `fun` anywhere else:

```
int sum = accumulate(m.begin(), m.end(),
                     [](int i, const std::pair<const int, int>& rhs)
                     {
                       return i + rhs.second;
                     });
```

Comment: It is std::pair<const Key, Value>

Comment: @jrok Thanks, I was fixing that.

Comment: @DieterLücking Right. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Element type of `std::map<K,V>` is `std::pair<const K,V>` for which `operator+` is not defined. You need to use 4 argument version of `accumulate` and supply your own addition operation:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> Pair;

int sum = accumulate(m.begin(), m.end(), 0,
    [](int i, Pair p){ return i + p.second; });
```

Comment: It is std::pair<const Key, Value> - but it does not matter here

Comment: How did you fix it dear jrok, dear jrok?

Comment: @Yakk `Element type of std::map<K,V> is std::pair<const K,V>` notice the `const` which wasn't there before. If that's not what you mean, what *do* you mean? :)

Comment: Your code lacks the fix.  Admittedly it just copies it, so little harm.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use lambda expression with `map<int,int>::value_type` as the binary operation.

```
sum = accumulate(m.begin(), m.end(), 0, 
                [](int v, map<int,int>::value_type& p) { return v + p.second; });
```